# Where in the registry does Windows store with which program to open certain file types?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista, windows-registry

After installing Adobe PDF reader, it opens files with the `.PDF` file extension. Ones' default web browser opens `.html` files and notepad opens `.txt` files, etc.

Where exactly in the registry are these filetype - program associations stored in the registry?

In other words, how does Windows know with which software/program it must open a certain file(type)?

Comment: Excellent Write-Up from 2018: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-file-association-explained-for-desktop/cfa62c00-82e0-4d05-b302-3444ab930bb7

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The *open with* associations are all stored in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

This is a special registry hive that combines the local user's associations in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` with the system's associations in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`.

Here's a shot from my registry for the PDF association you mention in your question:

[image: PDF file association in the registry]

Comment: The start of the solution section on this page (https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX115676) succinctly backs this up and shows how the assoc and ftype CMDs can be useful when looking at what specific file extension associations are, without needing regedit.

Answer (score 11):

Just to extend Gareth's answer:

From playing with the registry it looks like

- entries from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` override entries
  from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` in the
  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\Classes`
- setting file's extention association from command line using `assoc` command
  acts upon `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`
- setting file type association from command line using `ftype` command
  acts upon `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`

Answer (score 7):

With current Windows versions,

#1 First you need look up `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\[EXT]\UserChoice\ProgId` if it exists. If not, goto #5.

#2 The ProgId is a file-class, e.g. `Python.File` (=> goto #6) or similarly an application-id, e.g. `Applications\SciTE.exe` (=> goto #3)

#3 Locate the application id `Applications\SciTE.exe` like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\SciTE.exe\shell\open\command`. The default value is the command to run.

#4 Done.

#5 Lookup `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[EXT]` 's default value for a file-class, e.g. `Python.File`

#6 Lookup the file-class `Python.File` like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell`. The default value is a default command, e.g. `edit` (defaults to `open` if not existing).

#7 Look up its `edit` command like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\edit\command`. The default value is the command to run. Note: The other available commands for a file-class are shown in Explorer, when right-clicking on a file.

Note: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` joins the `Software\Classes` of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (higher priority)  and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

Comment: This is kickass answer, thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

While the answers are (probably, I didn't check) correct, the sane way to modify file associations is with the GUI Microsoft designed for it. (That is, if you are a user and not a setup developer.)

Here is one tutorial with nice pictures, I found it with google: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-associate-file-type-or-protocol-program

But you can just open start (win7 menu or win8 screen, doesn't matter) and type **file association**, **enter** and it should open the correct control panel link. (Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations).

Comment: Maybe that worked once upon a time. Now all Win10 gives me is "Look for an app in the Microsoft Store". BS.

Comment: Works for me now on Windows 11

Answer (score 1):

The problem with many of these methods is that Windows doesn't really handle the possibility of different executables having the same name.  When using the GUI, there is no way to know to which one they are referring.

That is because, in Win 7 anyway (I haven't checked win 10), the default program for explorer is stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\`
But if you look there you will find for example in the OpenWithList key, something like `LibreOfficeWriterPortable.exe` in my case.
But I have multiple versions of that program, all with the same name, so changing that key is not going to help.

To find what it actually points to, you have to go to (in my case)

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-966747605-1980359026-2421819745-1000\Software\Classes\Applications\LibreOfficeWriterPortable.exe\shell\open\command
```

to find out what that will actually open, i.e. what the named they are using actually points to.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10, you can identify that a program support what file extensions by 2 methods.

###### 1. "Set defaults by app"

Go to `Settings` -> `Defaults Apps` -> `Set defaults by app`. On the next page, Click `management` on the app that you want. In this situation, you can identify file associations that supported the app.

###### 2. Find in Registry

Go to Registry Editor. And find the entry of `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications`. This registry entry shows that where each program is logging its file associations. You can find the value of entry by the app name that you want.

In my case, I find an "IrfanView.exe" and its value is `computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IrfanView\Capabilities\FileAssociations`. if go to its location, you can find the result like below.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was trying to open a random extension with word pad, so what I did was:

1. Start -> Run -> cmd.exe
2. assoc .bhf=txtfile
3. Then find a file with that extension in windows explorer
4. Right-click -> Open With -> Choose Another App -> Select Checkbox "Always use this app to open .BHF files"
5. Select program of choice (if not visible select "More apps"/"Look for another app on this PC")

In my case, I didn't have the UI options for selecting the default program or the checkbox, until I ran the command in step #2.  I think once Windows thinks of a file like a "text" file, I guess it's no longer considered "too dangerous" to allow you to associate it as you see fit...

Comment: You're not seeking to understand the intent of the question.  He asked:

"In other words, how does Windows know with which software/program it must open a certain file(type)?"

He's obviously looking at understanding how Windows associates file types.  This answer addresses a common Windows problem that people run into trying to control program associations when Windows stops them from doing so.  The exact registry path was already provided in a different answer.  If the answer above doesn't work for somebody in the same situation, this answer will be much easier.

Comment: Where is it only referencing Windows 7?  I see "Windows 7", "Windows XP" and "Windows" generally tagged?