# assoc-ftype does not work properly on windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, file-association, inkscape, svg

I'm trying to associate `.svg` files to open with Inkscape's `inkview.exe`. Not being able to do so through conventional methods I'm trying the command line. What I did:

1. ran `assoc .svg=` and `assoc .svgz=`
2. ran `ftype svgfile=` and `ftype avgzfile=`
3. ran `assoc .svg=svgfile` and `assoc .svgz=svgzfile`
4. now when I run `assoc .svg` and `assoc .svgz` I get `.svg=svgfile` and `.svgz=svgzfile` respectively
5. the I ran `ftype svgfile="path\to\inkview.exe" %1` and same for `svgzfile`
6. now when I run `ftype svgfile` I get `svgfile="path\to\inkview.exe" %1`
7. but when I check the file explorer I see the files are associated with Internet Explorer!!!

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: Right click on that file and choose open with and then choose inkview as default.

Comment: @Biswapriyo sir, Thanks for your comment. But as I have mentioned in the OP the conventional methods do not work for some reason.

Comment: Did you restart Windows?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes sir.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSMS wont give up file associations](https://superuser.com/questions/1373310/ssms-wont-give-up-file-associations)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for Win10 as to why sometimes `assoc` will be ignored and seem to not do anything.

So I was trying to associate `.webm` files with `ffplay.exe`. So this is what I typed in CMD:

```
ftype ffplay.webm="C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffplay.exe" -hide_banner -loop -1 "%1"
assoc .webm=ffplay.webm
```

Even though I made sure that the above two commands had indeed permanently set those two values that I specified, these values were nonetheless seemingly just being ignored when I would double-click any `webm` file. Instead of using `ffplay.exe` to open my `webm` file, Windows would keep on using the app that I had setup months ago through the `default apps` interface in the windows settings.

So next I launched `regedit.exe` to doublecheck, and indeed `ftype` and `assoc` did their job like they were supposed to, as the following entries had been created in the registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.webm]
@="ffplay.webm"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ffplay.webm\Shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffplay.exe\" -hide_banner -loop -1 \"%1\""
```

But for some reason these settings were being ignored by Windows. As it turns out, the reason was that apparently `Windows 10` will ignore the above registry entries (set by `assoc` and `ftype`) if a different key is set for the same extension at a different location in the registry, and that location is in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\`, which in my case was:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.webm\UserChoice]
"ProgId"="Applications\\VLC.WEBM"
```

So to solve all this, all I had to do was delete the following key associated with `.webm` and all its sub-entries:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.webm]
```

Once that was deleted, Windows now would finally use the program I told it to use through `assoc` and `ftype`; no reboot necessary either! While it may be a very late reply, I hope this helps some folks out there that are having the same problem.

Comment: In my case I laso needed to delete [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.webm] for it to work.

Answer (score -2):

Try marking the %1 with quotes too -> `ftype svgfile="path\to\inkview.exe" "%1"`
Just had the same issue and this fixed it..

Comment: The documentation for assoc/ftype doesn't explain what the `"%1"` does. Not only that but the differentiation between file-extension and ftype-name is unclear. Such as is there a difference between `ftype .txt="notepad.exe"` `ftype txtfile="notepad.exe"`? Why does assoc/ftype don't behave properly especially when changing filetype-association?