# Weird image file association in windows 10 after update

Tags: windows-10, file-association, file-extension

I'm on windows 10 and I have Paint associated to some image file extension, e.g. *.png.

Since a recent update (either 1809, build 17763.475 or slightly earlier) when I double click a png file, it is printed rather than opened. The same thing happen if I associate the png to something else and right click->open with->paint, then it also prints.

Right clicking a png file shows this with paint  associated to png:
[image]

How to turn the default **Print** into **Open** as it used to? Am I the only one experiencing this?

Comment: What update?  Edit your question.

Comment: [Super User Post](https://superuser.com/questions/1366302/windows-10-wont-let-me-set-default-apps-for-file-extensions) and
[File Association Bug](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/11/09/microsoft-confirms-file-association-bug-in-windows-10-version-1803/) and 
[powershell fix](https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2018/11/08/about-file-associations/) is this the kind of thing you were facing? Or [Fix Open With](https://www.howtogeek.com/261076/how-to-fix-the-missing-open-with-option-on-the-windows-10-right-click-context-menu/) also have you run system checks `sfc /scannow` command and `scanreg /fix`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Paint.Picture\Shell`

Adding there the key `open` with a `command` key with value `"%systemroot%\system32\mspaint.exe" "%1"` and changning the shell default value to open fixed the problem.