# Change default file association with cmd or powershell

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

I would like to change the default file association of .xlsx with a script. I tried to change registry entries or with the command.

```
ftype <Name>="<Path>"
assoc .xlsx="<Name>"
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
I would like to open the file with a .cmd script and start excel later on from there.

Comment: You might first try to delete the registry key of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsx`. Suggest to Export it for backup.

Comment: @harrymc thanks. It changed the entry if you look it up with `assoc .xlsx` but it didn't work either when opening the file.

Comment: Try to follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1369178/8672). If it doesn't work for you, try to do it via the "Open with" context menu, then check what has changed in the registry.