# Find path of standard executable for a given file type in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe

Suppose I am running `cmd` and I open an application by typing for example `start document.pdf`

I want to get the exact path of the executable that opens `.pdf` files

Of course I could search the entire system for the executable but I suppose it would be faster this way because the path is already stored somewhere

I don't know if it makes a difference but I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly the exe locations are usually defined in the registry for example. I have .txt defined as opening with "notepad++".

So to find what the association of the file is, I'd have to go to:

```
"Open Control Panel > Control Panel Home > Default Programs > Set Associations".
```

From there it'd show Notepad++ is my default program.

I'd then have to go to the registry for Notepad++ e.g.:

`"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++"`

And see the complete file location there something like:

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++
```

EDIT:

Every program you install typically has a registry associated with it, where it can be configured.
Most programs details can be found in:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node" (64 bit)
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\" (32 bit)
```

So you'd need to use regedit.exe to these locations, find your program and view the location of the exe

Comment: Can you develop a bit more on the "go to the registry for Notepad++" part?

Comment: Edited the main post

Comment: Small observation: my program was not listed in ``HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\`` or ``HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`` so I ran the ctrl+f command to find it

Comment: It's not for certain - it's just the typical location. It can vary quite a bit.

Answer (score 15):

You can get this information using two command line tools: `assoc` and `ftype`:

> help assoc
>   Displays or modifies file extension associations
>
> help ftype
>   Displays or modifies file types used in file extension associations

You can combine them to produce information you need:
`for /f "delims== tokens=2" %a in ('assoc .pdf') do @ftype %a`

Running this directly from command line should give you path and parameters of program registered for `.pdf` files

Comment: Weirdly this doesn't give me the right program. [See here](http://i.imgur.com/ED5mElg.png), my standard ``.pdf`` program is Evince and your command is returning Acrobat Reader

Comment: @gsmafra You're right it seems that it does not always returns expected results, as discussed eg. here: http://superuser.com/questions/204354/how-do-i-get-ftype-assoc-to-match-windows-explorer and here:  http://superuser.com/questions/266268/where-in-the-registry-does-windows-store-with-which-program-to-open-certain-fil

Comment: I can run `assoc` and `ftype` from Command Prompt, but not from Powershell. Not sure why this is.

Comment: @AJM: `assoc` and `ftype` are intrinsic commands of cmd.exe, not separate exe's. So from Powershell, you must run them through cmd: `cmd /c assoc`

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks - didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the other solutions didn't work for me. But what did work is this:

1. Open the program by opening a file with the approprate file extension.
2. Go to task manager
3. Expand the appropriate process tree (if required)
4. Right-click on the program and click 'open file location'

This will bring you to the executable that is actually running the process.