# Running python behind corporate firewall

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, python

What is the best way of running python on Windows behind a corporate firewall?

The standard version installed does not have pip so I installed Anaconda but the version of the main package I need is too old. Any attempt to upgrade or download packages results in HTPP errors. IT support can't get through the firewall.

I'm not familiar with virtual environments and docker etc. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: I suppose you could download all Python modules, etc. from a PC not connected to the corporate firewall and then copy that to a USB thumb drive and then copy those from the USB thumb drive to the machine connected to the corporate firewall and then run that way.

Comment: Virtualization is no solution for your problem.  Can't you discuss this with your network administrators?  Why would they block access to a legit mirror if you need this for development?

Comment: I could have swore I saw someone on Windows once simply copy the Python directory from one machine with the modules, etc. to another and then was able to use it but had to set the environmental variables manually. I was helping a guy with something remotely from an IRC chat room and he showed me as part of what I was helping him with but perhaps it's not really that straight forward but I may test this one day myself though

Comment: Workaround - took computer home and installed it with no firewall but still looking for better option. BTW - Hotspot with work mobile phone failed. File association to wrong executable fixed with `https://superuser.com/a/963501/514126`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The python environment was successfully installed with Anaconda in both a large government department and a multinational company but IT teams in both organisations were unable to get through the firewall to install modules. Installing `pip` made no difference.

The workaround used was to download the packages off-site where they were accessible and use the `--offline` install process. This is demonstrated within an automated process in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857160/install-miniconda-and-extra-packages which unfortunately required versions to be hard-coded:

Off-site

```
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/jdcal-1.3-py27h8c72977_0.tar.bz2
```

On-site

```
conda install --offline jdcal-1.4-py27_0.tar.bz2
```

Look at the answer(s) to that question for alternative approaches.

Comment: This workaround will often be the best answer because corporations block access for some (especially developers) to maintain security for everyone, the security evidently stops very experienced IT administrators from bypassing it with proxy passwords (although not neccesarily the experience to use them), and if a change to firewall access was approved it is not useful unless it is timely.