# How to fix the directory of an extension's associated program

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association, wmic

On my Windows-10 PC, there are some files with extension `.dmupgrade`. Those should be opened with the program `C:\Program Files\<Company>\TaskbarUtility.exe`.

I also have another version of `TaskbarUtility.exe` on my PC, in the directory `C:\<Company>\Tools\TaskbarUtility\`.

For an unknown reason, while double-clicking on the `.dmupgrade` file, the program `C:\<Company>\Tools\TaskbarUtility\TaskbarUtility.exe` gets opened, so I've tried to change this: I've right-clicked on the `*.dmupgrade` file, pressed the `Change` button at `Opens with`, I chose the file `C:\Program Files\<Company>\TaskbarUtility.exe` and pressed `Ok`.
While double-clicking, it seems that the program `C:\<Company>\Tools\TaskbarUtility.exe` is used again for opening the file.

I've been looking into the registry, at following location:

```
 Computer\
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\
     Software\
       Microsoft\
         Windows\
           CurrentVersion\
             Explorer\
               FileExts\
                .dmupgrade\
                  OpenWithList
```

This only gives `TaskbarUtility.exe` as an answer (without any directory reference). The key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dmupgrade` exists but is not filled in.

I've checked the `PATH` environment variable, and apparently the directory `C:\<Company>\Tools` is not present there.

I've checked the `C:\Program Files\<Company>\Tools\TaskbarUtility.exe` (using a Ubuntu emulator app), it is not a link to the other program:

```
Prompt>file TaskbarUtility.exe
TaskbarUtility.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows
```

So my question is: when I configure a file extension to be opened with a particular program, how does Windows know in which directory to look for this program? Is it possible to handle this using `WMIC` commands?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd also check with `assoc .dmupgrade` in a cmd window and look up the value with ftype.

Comment: @LotPings: thanks. That solved my problem indeed. Please add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [some](https://superuser.com/a/283630/639112) people disgrace `assoc` and `ftype` as useless in this related [Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/204354/how-do-i-get-ftype-assoc-to-match-windows-explorer),
the above question is evidence for the opposite.

Both `assoc` and `ftype` are internal commands to cmd.exe

```
assoc /?
assoc.com /? 
assoc.exe /?
help assoc
```

Will return the same help text:

> ```
> Displays or modifies file extension associations
>
> ASSOC [.ext[=[fileType]]]
>
>  .ext      Specifies the file extension to associate the file type with
>  fileType  Specifies the file type to associate with the file extension
>
> Type ASSOC without parameters to display the current file associations.
> If ASSOC is invoked with just a file extension, it displays the current
> file association for that file extension.  Specify nothing for the file
> type and the command will delete the association for the file extension.
> ```

But there is no file present (So this doesn't work in PowerShell for example) Same applies for ftype.

To lookup what filetype is associated with an extension (here .txt):

```
> assoc .txt
.txt=txtfile
```

To lookup what command to **open** this filetype is used:

```
> ftype txtfile
txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

For other **verbs** you have to take the route over the registry

```
> Reg query "HKCR\txtfile" /S
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Text Document
    EditFlags    REG_DWORD    0x210000
    FriendlyTypeName    REG_EXPAND_SZ    @%SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe,-469

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\DefaultIcon
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-102

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\print

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\print\command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE /p %1

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\printto

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\printto\command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe /pt "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4"
```

**Edit: application to the original question:**
Hereby the results of `assoc` and `ftype` before:

```
Prompt>assoc .dmupgrade
.dmupgrade=dmupgrade

Prompt>ftype dmupgrade
dmupgrade=C:\<Company>\Tools\TaskbarUtility\TaskbarUtility.exe "%l"
```

The following command has been launched:

```
Prompt>ftype dmupgrade=C:\Program Files\<Company>\TaskbarUtility.exe "%1"
```

This failed at first, because I needed to perform this as an administrator :-), but after opening an administrator prompt, my problem was solved.